# Is there a way to have the passwordless sign in option from Microsoft Authenticator on an android emulator

Tags: android, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

Currently have an android application developed integrated with MSAL to provide authentication to AzureAD. Not able to enable passwordless authentication using an android emulator, where I can just log in to my application without signing in. Getting the message "this Feature is not supported on this device."

Is there a way to support this feature on an emulator

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cant register devices with an emulator, Microsoft does not support it.